# regex how to remove only a word including some particular letters

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for regex to get the result below.
The original sentence is:

```
txt="そう言え"
txt="そう言う"
```

and expected result is:

```
output="そう"
output="そう"
```

What I want to do here is to remove a word consists of two letters which includes character "言".

I tried `putput = re.sub(r"^(?=.*言).*$", "", txt)` in python but it actually removes the entire sentence. What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pattern that matches `言` followed by another word (denoted by `\w`), so that `re.sub` can replace the match with an empty string:

```
re.sub(r"言\w", "", txt)
```

Comment: god! it works! thanks and could you explain what really happens?

Comment: You're welcome. I've updated the answer with some explanations.

Comment: ok...so you mean if it's "言えばよかった" is it going to be an empty string? I just want to remove "言え" only and expect it come up with "ばよかった" in this case...

Comment: No, what I meant is that only `言` and the one word that follows it will be replaced with an empty string, not the entire rest of the string, so `言えばよかった` will become `ばよかった` after the replacement indeed.

Comment: got you you meant it "by another letter" rather than "by another word (denoted by \w). I know it's tricky to explain because it's Japanese...Thanks anyways and you helped me alot!